# Netbeans doesn't save Jasper reports libraries

Tags: java, netbeans, jasper-reports

I have a java project which I work on it with my friend from many PCs with netbeans 8.0.2, when I add the jasper reports library and try to access the project from another PC it asks me again to add all the JAR libraries, given that I have saved jasper reports libraries under c:\projects\iReports-5.5.0 for all PCs which we are worked from.

Comment: go to the `libraries >properties >libraries>libraries folder` 
it should be something like `.\lib\nblibraries.properties`
so netbeans will add all libraries  to lib in your project folder then you don't need to re add them again.

Comment: thanks alot< i will try it from my other PCs and see if it will stop asking to add them again.